# Best way to secure loose flooring

Tags: flooring

I have some loose flooring (I think it may be vinyl it's thin and has that plastic feel) that is sliding side to side and can easily be moved with my hand. I assume I can just glue it back down in some fashion but I'm not sure what product to use. I'm also not 100% sure what is under the  flooring so I want to make sure they work well together. Any advice is greatly appreciated this is in a bathroom next to a toilet.

[image: flooring]

Comment: Is that a toilet ? Your flooring may be falling apart and without more information or a detailed inspection we would be wrong to guess. Note the wet looking area may mean a wax seal failure or other leak .ok just re read it is a toilet , may need to pull the toilet to know for sure what to do.

Comment: I just looked at the photo and then my bathroom. It's not a wet spot that coloration goes through out the whole bathroom. It's just the style of the wood. I also just realized that is old flooring underneath. I assumed it was some type of mat, but it looks like they went over another vinyl floor. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes lots of folks overlay , I do in some cases not in others. You may get a construction adhesive to hold those in place. Some of the tiles have a peel and stick backing and that usually works well on vinyl but most say for dry locations, you said the wet look was built in so I might try a water resistant adhesive like liquid nails. It should not take very much you don’t want to make bulges or have it bleed up through the cracks before it drys. There are some silicone sealant / adhesives that should really stick well to the vinyl and once dry water won’t bother that type. I focus on moisture because in a bathroom that has been a majority of the issues I have found.